# Deploy ASP.NET Web Services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment, asmx, executable

I have developed multiple WebServices in my project in ASP.NET. Now I need to deploy them as a single executable file. How can i do that?

Comment: As @abatishchev mentioned below you can't do that.. Is that really your requirement? or do you need something else? If you could put your actual scenarion we might be able to help

Comment: What sort of web services? How do you intend to host them?

Comment: ok let me rephrase it....say i have 5 individual services and i want to generate them as a single msi..what do i do

Comment: my scenario is i have 5 webservices and i want to deploy it such that the user just needs to click on one link to execute all...

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy a web service as an executable, AFAIK